# Ошибка ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

У меня есть пакет модулей и он включает в себя такие файлы:

```
package:
   __init__.py
   __main__.py
   main.py
   sequence_creation.py
   sequences_operations.py
```

В main.py я импортирую sequence_creation и sequence_operations.
В __init__py прописано
`__all__ = ['sequences_operations', 'sequence_creation', 'main']`.
Когда я импортирую этот пакет и вызывают функцию dir(), печатается такая ошибка:

```
File "<длинный путь> ... main.py", line 8, in <module>
import sequences_operations as so
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sequences_operations'
```

Как её исправить?

Answer (score 2):

У вас файл называется `sequence_operations.py`, а вы вызываете `sequenceS_operations` (буква `s` лишняя). Естественно, такого модуля нету, об этом Python нам и хочет сообщить. Вызывайте так: `import sequence_operations as so`

Comment: @Nitrolacs, если помог ответ, не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Нет особого смысла давать ответы на вопросы, вызванные опечаткой, как правило такие вопросы просто закрываются с соответствующей причиной ("Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям...")

Comment: дело не в опечатке, я просто торопился задать вопрос и не заметил, как пропустил букву (такую ошибку ide сразу подсвечивает, естественно я не мог так ошибиться), в проекте у меня точно все названия правильные